# How to track from omniture in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, adobe-analytics

In my iPhone app I am using Omniture to track.

The code I am writing in AppDelegate :

```
 OMAppMeasurement * s = [OMAppMeasurement getInstance];

/* Specify the Report Suite ID(s) to track here */
s.account = @"reportSuiteID";

s.currencyCode = @"USD";
/* Turn on and configure debugging here */

s.debugTracking = YES;

/* WARNING: Changing any of the below variables will cause drastic
 changes
 to how your visitor data is collected. Changes should only be made
 when instructed to do so by your account manager.*/

s.pageName=@"firstViewController";

s.trackingServer = @"trackingserver";
[s track];
```

And my console shows only one line :

**App Measurement Library compile time = Jan 25 2011 11:46:14**

Suggest me what I am doing wrong?

Is my code at right place?

And in site where can I see reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all our client we have used a different sintax for the implementation.
We put
OMAppMeasurement * s;
in the AppDelegate and all the configuration code in applicationDidFinishLaunching function.
This is the certified implementation found in all the Omniture Implementation Document.

```
#import "BasicExampleAppDelegate.h"
@implementation BasicExampleAppDelegate

OMAppMeasurement * s;

@synthesize window = window_;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    //Instantiate instance
    s = [[OMAppMeasurement alloc] init];
    //Setup application config variables
    s.account = @"RSID";  

    s.trackingServer = @"TRACKSERVER";  

    s.pageName = @"Main Page";

    [s track];

  [window_ makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (void)dealloc {
  [s release];
  [window_ release];
  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: @Claudio Sermenghi : Thanks a lot, I want to know more things like, What if I want to track other pages? Is this code going to track only "Main Page"?

Comment: This is the configuration code that instantiate the tracking object and send the first pageView to the Omniture server. In order to track all the other action you have to put the call to s.pageName = @"New Page Name" and [s track] in every action you want to track (ex. Button Push, Page Reload, App Navigation)

Comment: @Claudio Sermenghi : Thanks. I got it. One more doubt I have is, as you say to put the call to s.pagename=@"New Page Name" and [s track], should I create object ( OMAppMeasurement *s = [[OMAppMeasurement alloc] init]; ) on every page I want to track?

Comment: I think the s object is Global because is created outside the AppFinishLaunching Function. We don't create it anyway.

Comment: So if I want to use it in other pages should I have to use like appDelegateObj.s.page = @"First View" and so on??

Comment: I think that s.pageName=@"First PageView" ans [s track] is enough.

Comment: I have tried this but can't find events are tracked or I don't know how to check it. Please guide me how to check reports for custom events? And how to integrate custom event..?

Answer (score 0):

Check if all necessary files and frameworks are included in your project ("OMAppMeasurement.h" and the frameworks libOmnitureAppMeasurement-iPhoneDevice.a and libOmnitureAppMeasurement-iPhoneSimulator_4_0_GM.a).

Try to create a NSDictionary with your own tracking data and use `(void)track:(NSDictionary *)variableOverrides`. There are no positive sign (as an log statement) if the tracking was successful.

The reports can be seen on the Omniture Website.

Edit:
The initialization code had to be in the UIAppDelegate. The [track] call had to be where you want to track some data (e.g. in the init methods of some UIViewController or after some button was pressed).

A Guide can be found [here](http://bit.ly/fBlxX3)

Comment: Thanks for the input. Can you please give a brief tutorial or reference of some article where in I can better understand Omniture? Also is the code placed in the right place? It is currently under my AppDelegate.

Comment: Thanks again. So in the code in question, I have to remove [s track] and s.pagename? And in other pages should I use object of AppDelegate itself or create different objects for different pages?

Comment: If I want to track data (like s.pageName, s.currencyCode,etc) from different views, what should be my code in AppDelegate and in other views? (say firstViewController, secondViewController).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this guide: http://www.2shared.com/document/dfkGsrwu/App_Measurement_for_iPhone_Imp.htm

helped me a lot, loads of information :)